# Проблема при трансформации объекта в unity?

Tags: unity3d

Когда я трансформирую объект, его меш сетка искажается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в кастомном масштабе (свойство Scale) объектов. При повороте объектов с Scale отличным от (1,1,1) возможна деформация мешей ([вот наглядный пример](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JtMeLk_MA5KTsVb_HOixxbdRSUP7p1k9/view)). Используйте "правильные" 3D модели, что бы не приходилось изменять их масштам.
Возможно (не проверял)деформации не будет, если изменения Scale будет пропорциональным, т.е. (1,1,1), (2,2,2), (5.75,5.75,5.75) и тд